# How to use UIImage to show picture at the same time let the black part of pic hidden

Tags: swift

I just have processed picture with thresholding with Swift 4.2, and OpenCV. However, I want to use the result UIImage as foreground to overlay the other background image. At the same time, I want to crop the black part of the foreground, and leave only the white part visible. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just got it!
I modify the Mat before I transform it to UIImage. The basic method is naive. I only determine the value of the 4th dimension of Mat, which represents the opacity. (You can ignore the inversion. That's used for keeping the part I want to left)

```
    int size[3] = { resultGrayMat.rows, resultGrayMat.cols, 4 };
    cv::Mat resultRGBAMat(3, size, CV_32F, cv::Scalar(0));
    cv::cvtColor(resultGrayMat, resultRGBAMat, cv::COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
    for (int i = 0; i < size[0]; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size[1]; j++) {
            resultRGBAMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[0] = 255 -  resultRGBAMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[0];
            resultRGBAMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[1] = 255 -  resultRGBAMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[1];
            resultRGBAMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[2] = 255 -  resultRGBAMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[2];
            resultRGBAMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[3] =(resultRGBAMat.at<cv::Vec4b>(i,j)[0]==255)? 255:0;
        }
    }
```